# I can't follow a passage in the textbook of complex variable of R. Greene and S. Krantz

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm reading the textbook *Function Theory of One Complex Variable* third edition of Robert Greene and Steven Krantz and at page 164 at the beginning of the proof of the theorem 5.2.2 it says:

> According to the lemma, there is a $\delta _1>0$ such
> that every point of $D(P, \delta _1) \setminus \{P\}$ is a simple point of $f$. Now choose $\delta , \epsilon  > 0$ as follows: Take $0 < \delta  < \delta _1$ such that $Q \notin f (D(P, \delta ) \setminus \{P\})$. Choose $\epsilon  > 0$ such that $D(Q, \epsilon ) \subset  f (D(P, \delta ))$ **and so that $\boldsymbol{D(Q, \epsilon )}$ does not meet $\boldsymbol{f (\partial D(P, \delta))}$**; this choice is possible because $f (D(P,\delta ))$ is open by Theorem 5.2.1 and because $f$ is continuous.

Note: above we have that $Q=f(P)$ and $f$ is a nonconstant holomorphic function.

What I can't see is why we can choose a $\epsilon >0$ such that $D(Q, \epsilon )$ does not meet $f (\partial D(P, \delta ))$, I don't see why continuity of $f$ can ensure that, as much I can see that $f^{-1}(D(Q,\epsilon ))\subset f^{-1}(f (D(P,\delta )))$.

Comment: It's not compact and one is a subset of the other, what does that tell you about interior points and neighborhoods?

Comment: What is a simple point?

Comment: @porridgemathematics it means that $f'(x)\neq 0$

Comment: I think I can see why this holds if we assume that $f \restriction D(P ; \delta)$ is injective.. but this isn't exactly helpful because we can only assume $Q \notin f(D(P ; \delta) \setminus \{P \})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer was simple after all. Thank you to @CBBAM for the hint.

I think the book was wrong here as we need to ensure that $Q\notin f(\partial D(P,\delta ))$, otherwise the statement will be trivially false. But we can fix it easily choosing a smaller $\delta _2$, that is, for $0<\delta _2<\delta $ we have that $Q\notin f(\overline{D(P,\delta _2)}\setminus \{P\})$, therefore $Q\notin f(\partial D(P,\delta _2))$. And as $f(\partial D(P,\delta _2))$ is compact and $\mathbb{C}$ is a metric space, then its easy to show that the distance between $Q$ and $f(\partial D(P,\delta _2))$ is positive, so such $\epsilon >0$ exists.

Comment: I was under the impression we cannot change $\delta$? It seems like you've chosen a smaller one in this answer.

Comment: @porridgemathematics we need to ensure that $Q\notin f(\partial D(P,\gamma  ))$, otherwise the statement is false. I think the book was wrong here.

Comment: That's what I was alluding to. Glad were on the same page.